# Prolema método find laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar usar un nuevo modelo.
Desarrolle un proyecto bastante extenso en laravel y ahora no soy capaz de realizar los siguiente.

cuando ejecuto

```
$pod= Albaranentrega::find($viaje_id);
```

No me encuentra ningún resultado

La tabla a la que hace referencia tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
id|viaje_id
```

Sin embargo si ejecuto:

```
$pod= Albaranentrega::find($id);
```

Si que encuentra el registro

Tengo otros modelos que funcionan realizando consultas identicas.
He estado revisando el código del proyecto y no recuerdo que hace que funcione esta consulta.

Es la relación entre las tablas de la base de datos?

Es la relación entre los distintos modelos done indicamos los "hasmany" "belongto" etc....

He revisado todas las partes el código y no encuentro el error por ningún lado. Espero que podáis orientarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien como la respuesta que ya te publicaron. `find()` apunta a la llave de tu tabla.

Otra opción para obtener lo buscado es hacer lo siguiente:

```
$pod = Albaranentrega::whereRaw('viaje_id = ?', [$viaje_id])->get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Es porque [`find()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) apunta a la llave primaria.

Para hacer lo que quieres puedes usar:

```
$pod = Albaranentrega::where('viaje_id', $viaje_id)->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Con el fin de guiar a futuros visitantes de esta respuesta, aquí está el código fuente del código find() del cual se habla en esta pregunta:

```
/**
 * Find a model by its primary key.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $id
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]|static|null
 */
public function find($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    if (is_array($id) || $id instanceof Arrayable) {
        return $this->findMany($id, $columns);
    }

    return $this->whereKey($id)->first($columns);
}
```

Como se puede ver, se busca por la llave primaria, y se puede hacer una búsqueda de más de un id, pasando un array.

En caso que se tenga otra llave primaria (no compuesta) distinta a id, se puede especificar fácilmente con una propiedad en el modelo:

```
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

---

Por último, una forma más bonita de hacer una consulta con un solo campo es la siguiente:

```
$pod = Albaranentrega::whereViajeId($viaje_id)->first();
```